# Dynamic filter that combines three tables using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a dynamic filter that combines three tables in flask-sqlalchemy. I can get it working with one table but I'm struggling to see how this should work with more than one table.

Presently I've tried to join the table `UserInClub` and `User` but I get the error `TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable`. I've tried to do the join before I start any queries but I can't figure out how I can then construct a dynamic query as I'm trying to do below. Also is it possible to use a group_by to have all users within a single list if they are in multiple clubs?

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_by = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    user_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)

    @classmethod
    def filter_user(
        cls,
        created_by,
        club_name=None,
        user_name=None,
        ):

        query = cls.query.filter_by(created_by=created_by)

        if user_name:
            query = query.filter_by(user_name=user_name)

        if club_name:
            query = query(User, UserInClub
                 ).filter(User.id==UserInClub.id
                 ).filter(Club.club_name=club_name)

        return query.all()


class Club(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    club_name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)


class UserInClub(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    club_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('club.id'), nullable=False)
```

Comment: replace the expression within the `if club_name:` with this one `query = query.join(UserInClub).join(Club).filter(Club.club_name==club_name)` to fix the error that you get.

Comment: Do you have any other data in `UserInClub` or is this table just for the purpose of enabling many-to-many relationship?

Comment: I have more data in UserInClub, I think I need to use a full outer join? I'm not sure if `query = query.join(UserInClub).join(Club).filter(Club.club_name==club_name)` would do that?

Comment: replace `.join(...)` with `.outerjoin(...)` and you should be fine, you clearly do not need "full outer join".